# How to change the text that a div has when you scroll to the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked on Stack Overflow for a solution however I cannot find one that will work with my project.

What i'm trying to do is change the text in the H1 that has the title relevant to the part of the page that the user is on. For instance it could say section 1 then when you scroll down it changes to section two. I need to do it like this because it's a fixed title that lies underneath a fixed navbar and it should always be there. So to have a solution that would change the contents of it when the next div is at the top of the page would be just what I need.

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky" class='a1'><h1 class='titleMusic noSelect'>Arcade Fire</div>
```

Thats the HTML

```
function sticky_relocate() {
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
} 
else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
}
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
    });
```

Thats the Javascript to make the Div 'Sticky' fixed to the top of the page when it gets to the top of the page. I need the text 'Arcade Fire' to change to Section 2 (will do for now) when the div section 2 reaches the top of the page.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle, codepen of codecademy example?

Comment: Which div / element in your markup are you trying to update? It's a fairly simple task, but you've not made it clear WHICH div / title should be updated with WHICH contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this in scroll event

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > $('section_1').offset().top 
   && $(window).scrollTop() < $('section_1').offset().top + $('section_1').outerHeight(true)
){
   $('#sticky > h1').text('Section 1');
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4up5a43d/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot! Been looking a long time for a solution. Is there anyway of also changing the background colour of the div as well as the text

Comment: @GeorgeBaker you can simplify your code by using a function like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4up5a43d/3/  ... and you can make simple equation in function to make action happen before section reach to the bottom of the fixed div like https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4up5a43d/5/  .. I just add - 200 in function just to see the action you can change it with your fixed div height .. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks so much! You've been very helpfull